# How to handle the [image-charts] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-creation-process

The [image-charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image-charts) tag has just been created, has 3 questions, and as far as I can see, it's about a charting API, so it could be on-topic.

There are several things that bother me about this tag, though:

- 2 of the 3 questions in this tag are clearly off-topic and have been closed
- The on-topic question is very close to customer support
- The 2 off-topic questions don't ask about the product, but ask about graphing products, and have an answer about the product.
- The answers on the tag discussing image-charts look a bit overly promotional to me. They do disclose affiliation.

<sub>The user creating the tag is also the CTO of image-charts.com, but that shouldn't really influence if the tag is appropriate or not</sub>

How to handle this tag? Should we just let it be, since it could be on-topic? Or should we remove it?

Comment: To me that single question is on-topic (not customer support), so the tag should be valid. Naturally the  CTO as anyone else should be able to answer he/she just need to be very careful with affiliation *we've just released what we call"* seems a bit weak it would be better if they added a clear disclosure/affiliation as "Disclosure: I work for...",  maybe a helpful comment under answer could solve this issue.

Comment: *However, the editing of the off-topic questions adding tag is not correct according to me (the questions did not ask for that specific library), I have chosen to roll them back* this https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1535958/revisions and this https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16003624/revisions

Comment: Hello! Thanks a lot for this informations :) I will replace my comments with "disclosure: I work for..." indeed that's a better idea. We would like to use the image-charts tag for image-charts community questions (like other SaaS do) is that an issue?

Comment: @FGRibreau Thanks for replying. It's not an issue to answer questions on Stack Overflow, and very much appreciated, as long as these questions are on-topic here. You can refer to [Can I support my product on this site?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support) for some guidance. [How not to be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) is also a good read. In general, try to stay factual and avoid unnecessary linking, advertisement talk, many images of the product, things like that.

Comment: Duly noted @ErikvonAsmuth!

Comment: I updated my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51661409/image-charts-com-api-distorted-results-when-providing-extendedencoded-data accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the tag itself is on-topic, then there's obviously nothing wrong with the tag. Whether the questions that use the tag are good questions/on-topic is a separate concern from the tag itself.

Yes, it takes a question to create a tag, and questions should always be on-topic, but... there's nothing preventing future questions in this tag from being high-quality, on-topic questions, is there?

So we should not remove the tag itself, and rather handle the questions themselves. If they get closed and removed for quality or topicality purposes, the system will remove the tag for us.

*NB - it already looks from the comments like the CTO and tag creator has worked to cleanup his post in the tag, which shows further good faith in the tag, IMHO*.